# How to create a downloadable file button on form

Tags: download, netsuite

I want to create a button on a purchase order form to download in one file all the different item lines in a csv file.

I created a suitlet file and a user event script.
The user event script create a button that redirect on the url of my suitlet script to execute a function.
For now a create a file csv in a folder, but I don't know how redirect on the file url or to directly download the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the file, get the url property (it's not a link to the NS record/file it's a download link), open the url.

In SuiteScript 1.0

```
var file = nlapiLoadFile('file_id');
var url = "https://system.netsuite.com" + file.getURL();
window.open(url, '_blank');
```

In SuiteScript 2.0

```
var filePath = file.load({
  id: 'Images/Desert.jpg'
});
var url = file.url;
window.open(url, '_blank');
```

Comment: How to use 'window', should I include a module or something cause If I use window.open(url, '_blank') I have an error "ReferenceError: "window" is not defined."

Comment: OK so , the only solution I found is to add my code in the user event script instead of suitlet script :  form.addButton({id: 'custpage_downloadcsv',label: 'Download CSV',
                    functionName: "window.open('" + downloadcsv(context.newRecord.id) + "','_self');"
                });

Comment: Just asking even if I think I already know the answer : with this code it's a redirection. There is a way to directly download the file not just display the content and -> download it with the navigator ?